# Capturing kubectl set command in terraform

Tags: terraform, kubectl

We have a case where we need to update AWS EKS CNI config on the daemon set. But the solution is only through kubectl command. How do we update an existing daemonset with specific values through terraform code? The requirement is that the solution has to be in IAC. The equivalent kubectl command given is

`kubectl set env daemonset -n kube-system aws-node WARM_IP_TARGET=2,MINIMUM_IP_TARGET=12`

The values shown in numbers are planned to be variables in terraform.

Comment: The Terraform resource corresponding to the CNI Daemonset is aws_eks_addon. Cant you iterate in the addons variable with a for_each and assign ? lastly  apply with auto approve.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for doesn't exist. Here is the open Terraform Github issue for what you are asking for:

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/723

Even if that did exist, I wouldn't consider that IaC as it's not declarative (might as well just run a bash script).

In my opinion, the real solution is for AWS to allow the provisioning of bare clusters so that "addons" can be managed completely through IaC tools. But that also does not exist:

https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/923

The closest you're going to get will be to use a null_resource to execute the patch. Here's an example in that Github issue:

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/723#issuecomment-679423792

So your final result will look similar to this:

```
resource "null_resource" "patch_aws_cni" {
  triggers = {
    always_run = timestamp()
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
# do all those commands to get kubectl and auth info, then run:
kubectl set env daemonset -n kube-system aws-node WARM_IP_TARGET=2,MINIMUM_IP_TARGET=12
EOF
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply erricfossas. I appreciate it. I will test this and get back to you. I will include the values inside heredoc as variables.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes the script based on this answer work. Appreciate your time and support for this initiative. Many thanks!